# Deploying VueJS to GitHub Pages

Tags: vue.js, github-pages

I have followed the [guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages) to deploy a VueJS app to GitHub pages step by step and it throws an error `GET https://jedrekdomanski.github.io/bikeramp-front/ 404 ()`

My repo (`gh-pages` branch): https://github.com/jedrekdomanski/bikeramp-front/tree/gh-pages

Website: https://jedrekdomanski.github.io/bikeramp-front/

#### script

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# abort on errors
set -e

# build
npm run build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd dist

# if you are deploying to a custom domain
# echo 'www.example.com' > CNAME

git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io
# git push -f git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git master

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>
git push -f git@github.com:jedrekdomanski/bikeramp-front.git master:gh-pages

cd -
```

#### vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/bikeramp-front/'
    : '/'
}
```

I am serving the app from `gh-pages`, like they said.

#### Source

`Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the gh-pages branch.`
What am I doing wrong?

#### package.json

```
{
  ...
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "vue": "^2.4.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: are you working with vue CLI 3?

Comment: I don't know, I don't remember but I think I don't. I struggled to even generate an app usign vue-cli. I have added my package.json to the description.

Comment: in package.json it seems that you're not using vue cli 3 and you're following steps to deploy your application using vue cli 3 documentation, please provide the project structure

Comment: in your repo you're missing to push the `dist` folder which contains `build.js`

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to set `baseUrl` to full path instead of relative path, since there is limitations for relative path

Refer: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

**Update:**

Interesting that I notice after switching to full path, it works, then when switch back to relative path, it seems still working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I deployed my Vuejs App to a github page:

I add a new file in the root project (next to package.json, ...): vue.config.js

I write inside:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/something/",
  outputDir: "docs",
};
```

Such that your url will be:

**name.github.io/something/**

the "docs" gives the output Folder for the `npm run build` because Github allows you just to choose between /(root) and /docs for the GitHub Page. So in this case on GitHub in the Settings of your project, go to Pages and for Source select /docs.

After that you have just to write following git order:

```
yourProject(main)$ npm run build
git add .
git status      (to be sure)
git commit -am "your commentar"
git branch -M main      (only if yourProject(master)is written instead of sfes(main) => GitHub changed master to main)
git push -u origin main
```